# Current Time/Date Code Error

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I get Current Time as this code is giving (Time-->Thu Jan 01 05:56:27 ACT 1970)??

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS"); 
         Date time = new Date(); 
         String currentTime=timeFormat.format(time);
         time=timeFormat.parse(currentTime);
         System.out.println("Time-->"+time);
         salesOrder.setOrderTime(time);
```

Comment: use DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();  instead of DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss:SS");

Comment: Where *exactly* do you believe the problem is?

Comment: The problem is in formatting. He has not provided the Day,year specifier, thats why it is acting that way. Or OP can use this with proper formatting : DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
```

instead of

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss:SS");
```

The problem is in formatting. You have  not provided the Day,year fieldr, thats why it is acting that way. Or You can use this with proper formatting :

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
  c.setTime(time);
  System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+ "  "+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ " "+ c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Where `time` set in `Calendar object` is time that is not parsed/formatted using simpleDateFormat. 
From `calendar object`, you can get individual month , day , year and use it the way you like, or you can just call `c.getTime()` to get the `Date object`.

Comment: I want separate Date and Separate time ? How em I gonna get them, I mean, I am having two separate Columns in Data Base, One for Date and other for Time, My Bean is Mapped using Hibernate with Data Base and I need Object of Date type as in Data Base, I am having (Date type) for Date and (Time type) for Time in Data Base now the format you told will produce a whole string including date and time ? How will I separate them to store them in Different coloumns in Data Base?

Comment: Answer has been modified, check it .

Answer (score 1):

Class `java.util.Date` is not suitable for storing only a time-of-day (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds). Class `Date` is a timestamp, it contains a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Use `LocalTime` from the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library for this instead.

Note: What you are doing in your code is first formatting a `Date` object to a `String`, and then parsing it back to a `Date` again, throwing away the day, month, year part. What you end up with is a `Date` object that's set to a number of hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: Jesper, I am having two separate Columns in Data Base, One for Date and other for Time, My Bean is Mapped using Hibernate and I need Object of Date type as in Data Base, I am having (Date type) for Date and (Time type) for Time. I don't know how to Use that Joda Time Library could you give any Example.

Answer (score 0):

Your format only contains hours and minutes and seconds.  Given just a time of day with no date component, `DateFormat.parse()` does not fill in the current date; it falls back on the epoch of the system, "time zero", which is January 1, 1970.  If you want a date string that can be turned back into a Date object, you need to include the year and month and day as well as the hour.

Comment: I am having two separate Columns in Data Base, One for Date and other for Time, My Bean is Mapped using Hibernate with Data Base and I need Object of Date type as for Data Base, I am having (Date type) for Date and (Time type) for Time. I don't know how to get the time and date separately to store them in there respective Setter's.